# GSA - Sort by metadata - sorts by relevancy first - missing results

Tags: google-search-appliance

Hi fellow GSA Developers,

[Sort by Metadata](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1083224)

The official document says below, link above,

> The sorting occurs only on the 1000 most relevant results for the
>   specific query.
>
> When sorting by metadata, the total length of the metadata attr:value
>   pair cannot exceed 121 characters. Exceeding the maximum character
>   limit causes results to be unsorted.

I'm using the below GSA query which is a 'soryby' metadata with no search terms,

```
http://GSA-HOST/search?
access=p&
site=POC&
output=xml&
client=default_frontend&
q=&
num=1000&
filter=0&
requiredfields=TYPE:car&
partialfields=KEY:12345&
getfields=*&
start=0&
sort=meta:PRODUCT_ORDER&
start=0
```

And I have an equivalent DB Oracle SQL query with me with an Order By. When I compare the table which is the result of my SQL query, lots of results are missing in GSA. So,

- Does GSA mean that the missing documents are irrelevant documents?
- I did open those missing documents and found them to be full of relevant text
- I'm not passing any 'q' parameter and it is a plain fielded search so how is the relevancy even calculated? based on what?
- I tried adding the empty 'q' parameter with a title of a missing document in exact phrase search and the document showed up
- Now I'm not able to understand what is happening behind the scene and trying to understand a reason for those missing documents.
- Changing 'filter' parameters to various values did not have any effect.
- Although everything works as expected when the result count does not exceed 1000. GSA is able to exactly sort it like a DB
- However adding a 'rc=1' gives me a count that matches with DB but still the GSA sort-by metadata does not behave like a SQL ORDER BY

Anybody has experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

The GSA expects a query term since you are performing a search.

What you are describing is really wanting to use the GSA to execute a database query and return all results.

One way to get around this is if all of your content sources have document URIs that include your company name then you could make your q value be your company name.

i.e if every document URL was like this:

http://www.acme.com/blah/blah/blah
http://gsa-db-adaptor.acme.com:5959/doc/12345858

etc.

If your "q" value is "acme" then you'd get a hit on every document so sorting by meta data should work in this case (again, relevancy might be an issue if the documents you are expecting are beyond the first 1000.

That's how I would tackle this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes. You are correct in saying "GSA to execute a database query and return all results" and No, it does not work either. I tried searches with 'http' and also domain name, so adding a dummy 'q' parameter did not help. There is really something else that is happening  based on which GSA is removing certain results.

Comment: And it works exactly like a DB query if the number of results is less than 1000

Comment: Terry is right. What you would put under the query would be something that is present on every single record. Try to put the full domain name http://www.acme.com This worked for me on multiple different projects. If it doesn't, I suggest you get in touch with Google Support.

Comment: Thank you for response. No luck. I tried all possible combinations and I also have a meta-data which will be the same for every single document. I gave that meta-data value in the 'q' and still several documents did not turn up. The only possible explanation is, google is somehow determining those missing documents as less relevant documents (not relevant to be qualified in the top 1000) but how they determine, only they can answer. How are they even calculating relevancy when there is no 'q' parameter.

Comment: A requiredfields=TYPE:car should bring all documents with metadata type-car with the mentioned sort order is the desirable result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can fix your problem but you can give a try by using sitesearch or as_sitesearch or site request parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, i tired out all possible query parameters which can somehow influence the relevancy and make GSA bring the missing documents but no luck.

Comment: The only way i was able to bring the missing document is by missing its title in the 'q' parameter which proves that the other conditions like the required and partial fields are still able to search of the missing documents.

Comment: Okay.Have you also tried using requiredfields with key alone? For example requiredfields=title (Don't add any value).

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure of the idea behind it but out of pure desperation I did try it and had an equivalent SQL query but had no luck. GSA is still not able to do an ORDER BY without missing some documents in-between.